# Lubuntu upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04 with nvidia-361 and xserver settings are empty

Tags: xorg, 16.04, xserver, nvidia-settings, xorg.conf

As the title suggests, I've just done an upgrade. Unlike other unlucky folk, I've had no problems with logging into the GUI. But it seems like the nvidia drivers are not properly installed. My xserver settings are empty.

If it helps, this was my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file at the time after install:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 361.42  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-13)  Tue Mar 22 18:37:28 PDT 2016

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I would have a dual monitor setup usually. My monitor is a Dell U2412M.

My graphics card is a GTX 970. Double-checked with `lspci | grep "VGA"`

`VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 [GeForce GTX 970] (rev a1)`

[image: display settings]

[image: nvidia-settings]

I have tried `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-settings nvidia-361`, moving `.nvidia-settings-rc` to `.nvidia-settings-rc.backup` as well as with the `xorg.conf` after trying versions 340 and 304 as well. On each I restarted `lightdm` as well as rebooting just to be sure.

Contents of one of my `.nvidia-settings-rc`:

```
#
# /home/<user>/.nvidia-settings-rc
#
# Configuration file for nvidia-settings - the NVIDIA X Server Settings utility
# Generated on Tue May 10 18:38:44 2016
#

# ConfigProperties:

RcFileLocale = C
ToolTips = Yes
DisplayStatusBar = Yes
SliderTextEntries = Yes
IncludeDisplayNameInConfigFile = No
ShowQuitDialog = Yes
UpdateRulesOnProfileNameChange = Yes

# Attributes:
```

[The following](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/defaye/9efbd3003d361fbaaf61c57f5afcbe88/raw/59dbc91e6e69146f6fc85b86e0672b37bd97c820/Xorg%2520log) is the output of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

Comment: For sake of sharing: on a perfectly fresh formatted install of Ubuntu 16.04 - where I used the Ubuntu "Additional Drivers" interface to switch from Nouveau to nvida-361 - there is no /etc/X11/xorg.conf file!  It works fine, as the Nvidia control panel works, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sad to say but I have had to resort to re-installing from scratch. I have opted for Kubuntu 16.04 instead of Lubuntu 16.04 this time around. The install was set to download all recommended third party drivers and updates and everything worked first time including recognition of my second monitor as well as correctly setting the native resolutions.

Upon attempting to install nvidia graphics drivers I then encountered the black screen issue. Whether or not using the `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` repository and installing `sudo apt install nvidia-364` helped I do not know. But it seems that my major issue was that I had to disable secure boot in BIOS, changing from Windows to Other OS.

So if you have the `nouveau` drivers by default as I did (you can check with `lshw -c video | grep -i driver` where `driver=nouveau` would ideally be `driver=nvidia`, then add the above repository, `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install nvidia-364` with a reboot may work for you too.

If you do encounter the first issue my question is about, check to see whether you have secure boot mode on in BIOS and disable it if it is on. I can only hazard a guess that the nvidia drivers were defaulting to a fallback that at least allowed a GUI, though I never figured out the cause of  the problem.

It is also worth noting that I get this issue with my DVDROM drive plugged in via SATA cable. This is likely a misconfiguration on my part but it is also another avenue of investigation if you get this problem.

Answer (score 1):

i found the nvidia-361 in the normal repo was really buggy and switched to the nivida-364 from the graphics-drivers repo.

More info on the repository
https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

how to install it and use nvidia-364

```
apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
apt-get install nvidia-364
```

then reboot.

Comment: No joy unfortunately.

Comment: have you checked your nvidia-settings package is the one from the repo ?

my configuration was an optimus but on closer examination i can see yours is different.  Definitely don't use nouveau yet.

Comment: This difference may be as I am using Lubuntu and not Ubuntu, but otherwise the same I should imagine. In any case, I can't check it now because the system was a reformat

Comment: Sub distro's are very unlikely to work differently unless they are not of the same era

Comment: The assumption I've made here is that you may have mistaken the way it looks aesthetically for the way it works programmatically, in any case if it was different, your updated answer may help someone else - I will never know now

Answer (score 0):

I also just upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04 with the nvidia-361 drivers and had all my fonts screwed up. I just discovered that I didn't have an xorg.conf file at all (is that what you meant by saying it was empty?) but I did have three xorg.conf files with a date code attached, one of which was the date of my upgrade. Examining it, I discovered it had the settings from my previously (properly configured) installation, so I simply did the following, and it worked:

sudo cp xorg.conf.*datecode* xorg.conf